# How to enter only Integer values in BlackberryTipCalculator in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

How to enter only Integer values in BlackberryTipCalculator in Java?

Answer (score 0):

i haven't done anything on blackberry, but generally i'd approach the problem as follows:

Check event: when text field is modified, check if text field value contains non-integer characters. If so, remove it.